# Why is my HttpPost method not firing from my Asp.Net Core Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

New to Asp.Net Core Razor here.

I'm trying to hook up a simple button to save on my Razor page.
My [HttpPost]SaveDocument() method is not firing on the the "Save" button click.
Instead, the Index() method is firing.
I'm not sure what I've got hooked up incorrectly.

**Here is a snippet of my Razor Page definition:**

```
@model SampleViewModel
@{ Layout = "_DevExtremeLayout";
    ViewBag.Title = "Sampe Title";}

<form method="post">
    <div id="InputFormPanel" class="InputFormPanel">
        <partial name="@Model.ChildViewName" model="@Model.ChildViewModel" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input id="ApprovedBy" class="form-control" asp-for="ApprovedBy" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Title" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="SaveButton" type="submit" >Save Form</button>               
</form>
```

**Here is my model:**

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public object ChildViewModel { get; set; }
    public string ChildViewName { get; set; }
    public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is a snippet of my controller:**

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Guid documentTypeId)
    {
        SampleViewModel viewModel = new SampleViewModel()
        {
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveDocument(SampleViewModel sampleViewModel)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Being new to this, I imagine I'm doing something foolish here/missing something.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe you need to add `action=SaveDocument` to your form so that it will change the url. As it stands, it appears it will make a request to index which does not have an `[HttpPost]` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't assign the action attribute on an HTML form it will post the request to the same page/route you're currently on, which in this case is your Index action.

So if you add an action attribute like so:

```
<form method="post" action="SaveDocument">
```

It should start working. Alternatively you can also rename the SaveDocument method to Index, there won't be any errors since the two method signature won't match. From a code organization point of view that's typically my preference since it makes it clear that the GET/POST actions are for the same page.